# Select @@identity in Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm going to implement database replication (merge publication, bi-direction) between two servers running SQL Server 2008 Standard edition. The setup is alright but it comes to a problem when synchronizing data.

The main task of my program is to let user register and after the `INSERT` statement is executed on my `member` table (with `uid` primary key and auto-incremented), it queries `SELECT @@identity;` for the max. primary key. The program then uses this key for insertion into another table.

All these work fine **without** replication.

But after replication, when doing `SELECT @@identity;` it returns back an **incorrect** primary key. (Suppose now `member` contains 100 members, after inserting a new record, it should have returned 101. But instead it returns 2 or 3 which is wrong and not what I expected.)

So my question is how to get a correct value using `SELECT @@identity;`.

I know the possible solution is `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, but I want to know how to fix this **without changing the source code**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to test `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to make sure it corrects the issue, then use that.  There's no way to fix something with bad code without rewriting the code, and `@@IDENTITY` is loaded with problems - that's why they made `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in the first place.

Comment: @@Identity should not be used. You should switch to using OUTPUT (scope_ideinty() works but has problems if parralleism is used, OUTPUT works in all conditions) and yes that requires code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@@identity is not a good solution and will return incorrect results since .  SCOPE_IDENTITY() is session based and will return the last inserted record for the session.  There isn't a way to correct this without a code change.